# Single word for the phrase "friends at high places"

Tags: single-word-requests

A person's "jack" is the slang for "friends at high places" in the part of the world where I belong to.

Thank you.

Edit: I split the long question as I was asked to.

Comment: This is two entirely different questions. Please split it so that they can be answered separately.

Comment: This might also be a good candidate to ask on http://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

"Connected".  As in: "He's connected; he can get anything you need, no matter how illegal."  This could also be phrased as "he has connections".  Just as an alternative for Brian Hooper's suggestion of Pull (which might fit your needs better).

Answer (score 1):

*[Pull](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pull)* might be a suitable word for this; a bit less slangy than *jack*; meaning (6):-

> Slang A means of gaining special advantage; influence: The lobbyist has pull with the senator.